# Json.NET SelectTokens not working if json contains empty array

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, jsonpath

I have a valid JSON object that contains multiple "en-US" keys, which I'm trying select. For that purpose I use the JsonPath

```
"$..en-US"
```

which is given to the SelectTokens procedure implemented by the Json.NET. It's a JSON framework for .NET . Everything is working fine and well as long as my JSON doesn't contain any empty array.
Here's an example:

```
var myJsonPath = "$..en-US";
var myJson = 
        @"{
            'controls': [
                {
                    'messages': {
                        'addSuggestion': {
                            'en-US': 'Add'
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    'header': {
                        'controls': []
                    },
                    'controls': [
                        {
                            'controls': [
                                {
                                    'defaultCaption': {
                                        'en-US': 'Sort by'
                                    },
                                    'sortOptions': [
                                        {
                                            'label': {
                                                'en-US': 'Name'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }";
var jToken = JObject.Parse(myJson);
var tokens = jToken.SelectTokens(myJsonPath);
```

Here, the **tokens** variable will contain just one element! That will be the "en-US" occurence BEFORE the empty array in the 'controls' of the 'header' object. However, when I just leave this 'header' object out:

```
var myJson = 
    @"{
        'controls': [
            {
                'messages': {
                    'addSuggestion': {
                        'en-US': 'Add'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                'controls': [
                    {
                        'controls': [
                            {
                                'defaultCaption': {
                                    'en-US': 'Sort by'
                                },
                                'sortOptions': [
                                    {
                                        'label': {
                                            'en-US': 'Name'
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }";
```

I will get all the 3 occurencies of the "en-US" as expected. Btw, if I validate my JsonPath on the first JSON object (i.e. which contains an empty array) in [an online tool](http://ashphy.com/JSONPathOnlineEvaluator/), then as expected, I get all the three "en-US" cases. This diverges from what I'm getting from the Json.NET. I'm wondering whether it's a bug or do I have to handle this case manually somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that has been fixed. Upgrade to the latest version of Json.NET.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the same situation as me where you're a bit stuck with respect to updating your version of Json.NET, you can work around the issue by doing something along the lines of this:

```
IEnumerable<JValue> vals = jToken
    .Desecendants()
    .Where(w => w is JProperty && w.Name=="en-US")
    .Select(s => s.Value);
```

Hope that helps! The vals array will contain the same tokens you would have gotten using the selector you were trying to use before.